# How to pass arguments in promise

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

I am using promise like this:

```
var restClient = {
    serveRequest: function(rUrl, type, body, rHeaders, rAsync, callback) {  
        var promise = jQuery.ajax({
           url: rUrl,
           type: type,
           data: body,
           headers: rHeaders,
           async: rAsync,
           contentType: "text/plain",
           dataType: "json"
        });

        promise.then(onSuccess, onError);   
    },
    onSuccess: function(data) {
        callback(data);
    },
    onError: function(msg) {
        console.log(msg.responseText);
    }
}
```

How can I pass arguments (callback) in promise.then onSuccess? I want to use that in onSuccess method later.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I am using promise like this

Well, first of all, you shouldn't. The purpose of promises is to be returned as results from asynchronous functions, so that you don't need callback parameters any more. You'd better just do

```
var restClient = {
    serveRequest: function(rUrl, type, body, rHeaders, rAsync) {  
        var promise = jQuery.ajax({
           url: rUrl,
           type: type,
           data: body,
           headers: rHeaders,
           async: rAsync,
           contentType: "text/plain",
           dataType: "json"
        });
        return promise;
    }
};
```

and let the caller of `restClient.serveRequest(…)` invoke `.then(…)`.

> How can I pass arguments (callback) in promise.then onSuccess?

You don't need that `onSuccess`. Just directly use

```
promise.then(callback, function(msg) {
    console.log(msg.responseText);
});
```

> I want to use that in onSuccess method later.

You cannot. It tries to use `callback`, but that is a parameter local to the `serveRequest` method - so `onSuccess` could at most be a local function in there, but not a method on its own.

Comment: I'd like to see how you use promises without callbacks.  I don't think that's what you really meant.

Comment: @jfriend00: Fixed. I meant that no function or method except `then` needs callback parameters any more.